# how do I get all the data on a CDTCommonProjectWizard

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am developing a project that inherits from CDTCommonProjectWizard, my question is how do I get all the data when select the finish button, I need the Project Name, the Project type and the toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [continueCreation()](https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/eclipse-doc36/org/eclipse/cdt/ui/wizards/CDTProjectWizard.html)

```
public class MyNewWizard extends org.eclipse.cdt.ui.wizards.CDTProjectWizard
{   

@Override
protected IProject continueCreation(IProject prj) {
    // This is run at the end of the creation process

    // The things you specifically asked for:
    // prj.getName() 
    // prj.getType() 
    // toolchainManagedBuildManager.getBuildInfo(prj).getManagedProject().getConfigurations()[0].getToolChain()


    return super.continueCreation(prj);
}
```